# Unable to read citations from bibliography file

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using a latex file to write a report. The said latex file requires me to have different chapters and plots in different folders. When I try to generate a pdf output from this latex file, I encounter errors which say `Citation 'citation name' on page 1 undefined.`. In short, the latex compilation fails to read entries of my bibliography file (`references.bib`).

This is a skeleton of the said latex file (`test.tex`)

```
\include{macpap2}

\documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis} 

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphics}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{appendix} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage[sort]{natbib} 
\usepackage[biblabels]{authorindex} 
\usepackage{minitoc} 
    \setcounter{minitocdepth}{3} 

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\title{Title Name}
\author{Firstname Lastname}
\college{College Name}
\renewcommand{\submittedtext}{\textit{Write something.}}
\degree{Degree name}
\degreedate{December 2018} 
\renewcommand{\crest}{\beltcrest}

\begin{document}

\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt

\begin{frontpages} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\maketitle

\end{frontpages}
\begin{romanpages}
\tableofcontents
\end{romanpages}

\input{chapter/chapter1}

%% BIBLIOGRAPHY %%
%
%\citeindexfalse % to stop indexing citations
%uncommnent next line to change bibliography name to references
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
%\begin{flushleft} % This is to left-justify the bibliography

\bibliography{references.bib} % Full path to bibtex bibliography file (e.g. "references.bib")
%   \adjustmtc %! To prevent tocbibind interfering with minitoc
%\bibliographystyle{agsm} % This one is modeled on the standard year/date referencing standard
%\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

This file has only one chapter (`chapter1.tex`). This is the skeleton of `chapter1.tex`.

```
chapter{\label{ch:chapter1}Chapter1}

\section{Preliminaries}
I want to cite these: \citep[][]{Caldwell2002, Daly2003}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.41\textwidth]{Plots/dino2.png}
    \includegraphics[width=0.41\textwidth]{Plots/dino2.png}    
    \caption{Two dinos.}
    \label{fig:Dinos}
\end{figure}
```

My bibliography file (`references.bib`) is given underneath.

```
@article{Caldwell2002,
title = "A phantom menace? Cosmological consequences of a 
dark energy component with super-negative equation of state",
journal = "Physics Letters B",
volume = "545",
number = "1",
pages = "23 - 29",
year = "2002",
issn = "0370-2693",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/S0370-2693(02)02589-3",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269302025893",
author = "R.R Caldwell"
}


@article{Daly2003,
  author={Ruth A. Daly and S. G. Djorgovski},
  title={A Model-Independent Determination of the Expansion and Acceleration Rates of the Universe as a Function of Redshift and Constraints on Dark Energy},
  journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
  volume={597},
  number={1},
  pages={9},
  url={http://stacks.iop.org/0004-637X/597/i=1/a=9},
  year={2003},
  abstract={abstract.}
}
```

I am using `Texmaker 4.5`. All files (`*.tex`, `*.bib`, `*.cls`, figures etc) used by this latex package can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1onhwp8VVyanrqCdzmj-rcNvHxZdH5EBK?usp=sharing).

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this latex package read and execute the contents of my bibliography file?

Comment: does removing the `.bib` extension help? i.e.: `\bibliography{references}`. When you run Bibtex, what are the error messages that you get?

Comment: @Troy : I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't help. This is the message that I get when when I run Bibtex on `test.tex` : `Citation 'Caldwell2002' on page 1 undefined` . In the subsequent line of the message, I see this: `Citation 'Daly2003' on page 1 undefined` .

Comment: Even though it was not the main issue here, you should follow Troy's advice and write `\bibliography{references}` without file extension. This is the officially supported syntax that can be guaranteed to work. Some systems are more forgiving when you include the `.bib` extension, but this is not guaranteed. My MikTeX system (on Win 10) will not process files if the `.bib` extension is included in the `\bibliography` call.

Comment: @moewe : I tried your suggestion. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce a bibliography with `bibtex` the source file should specify (1) at least one `bib` file, and (2) the bibliography style to be used (e.g., `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`). The `\bibliographystyle{...}` instruction is missing.